# Displaying road outlines but not segments i.e. no lines at intersections?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, cartography

[image]

I have the roads that I want to just display at outlines but not segments (I.e not disconnected from each road).

I am trying dissolve but its not working. Attached is a link to a package file of the data. Please help!  https://www.dropbox.com/s/55hqr9471v9qxwf/Road%20Test%20package.mpk

Comment: are your roads lines or polygons ?

Comment: @radouxju - they are Polygons - I am trying dissolve but its not working. Attached is a link to a package file of the data. Please help!  https://www.dropbox.com/s/55hqr9471v9qxwf/Road%20Test%20package.mpk

Comment: Have you tried @Lemur solution ? For polygons this is what I would have suggested. ("all white" layer with boundary width of 1 on top of "all black" layer with boudary width of 2  (Mapperz's solution is best for lines)

Comment: @user42720 I have noticed you have not accepted many answers yet, despite most of your questions being answered. I would suggest you go through your [previous questions](http://gis.stackexchange.com/users/28897/user42720?tab=questions) and start accepting some answers by clicking the check mark next to the best answer. This encourages users to continue answering your questions and awards them for their efforts.

Comment: Regarding the duplicate question above, the use case here is much simpler than that one, but the same solution applies.

Answer (score 3):

Use **Displaying roads using symbol level drawing**

*"Many users often need to display road networks and want to represent their connectivity in term of overpasses, underpasses, bridges, and so forth. This would occur in any situation where road connectivity and navigation pathways need to be portrayed."*

[image]

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s500000014000000

Comment: they are Polygons - I am trying dissolve but its not working. Attached is a link to a package file of the data. Please help! dropbox.com/s/55hqr9471v9qxwf/Road%20Test%20package.mpk

Comment: Symbol level drawing can also be achieved with polygons: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Dissolving_polygon_boundaries_using_symbol_level_drawing/00s500000025000000/

Answer (score 3):

One quick and easy trick I use is to have the layer in the map twice.  The top layer is displayed as a white line (or white fill & no outline if the layer is a polygon) and the bottom copy is black and the width is set to be just a bit wider than the top copy.

Answer (score 0):

You could Merge them, or Dissolve. This would create a separate feature class, but would do what you want.

Comment: @recuvata they are Polygons - I am trying dissolve but its not working. Attached is a link to a package file of the data. Please help! dropbox.com/s/55hqr9471v9qxwf/Road%20Test%20package.mpk

Comment: I'd like to, but that package is just too large - 200mb. Maybe make a smaller sample set and zip it up.

Comment: Hmm, appears to have downloaded anyway. I tried running Dissolve, but got an invalid topology error. The dataset may be too large for Dissolve to handle at ~800k features. You could try breaking it into smaller chunks. Dissolve doesn't work well with large numbers of features; see http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000005n000000